# How do convert row column values in to a column value

Tags: sql-server

How do we convert row column values into column values.

for  eg:-

I have 5 rows, each rows have 5 columns. I need to convert based on the ID.

My query is:

```
Select id,year,height,weight,date from user_det

---------------------------------------------------------
| Id |   Year       |   height|   weight|     date       |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |  20082009    |  122    |   23    |     4/15/2009  |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |  20092010    |  135    |   39    |     3/19/2010  |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 2  |  20082009    |  132    |   20    |     2/23/2009  |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 3  |  20142015    |  133    |   28    |     2/24/2015  |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

If I group by id maximum is 2. I need **Result** like below table

```
id | year1  | height1 |weight1 | date1   | year2    |  height2|weight2|date2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |20082009|  122    |  23    |4/15/2009| 20092010 | 135     | 39    |3/19/2010
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2  |20082009 | 135     |  20   |2/23/2009|          |         |       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3  |20152015 | 133     |  28   |2/24/2015|          |         |       |
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with pivot or conditional aggregation.  But, you need a column for the pivot:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then year end) as year_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then height end) as height_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then weight end) as weight_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then date end) as date_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then year end) as year_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then height end) as height_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then weight end) as weight_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then date end) as date_2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by year) as seqnum
      from user_det t
     ) t
group by id;
```